# How to write a good question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, best-practices

I face the problem of writing a good question in Stack-overflow sites.

What is the best way to write a good question?

Comment: Obligatory: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Though, honestly, I don't see a problem with your Stack Overflow questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/712960/basbous?tab=questions  Is there a specific instance which prompted this?

Comment: Shameless plug: http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/07/28/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-1-of-n/

Comment: I went through some of your questions. As a first step, don't write stuff like "am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help." or "thanks in advance"... As a second step, go through your questions and see what edits other people made. Learn from them.

Comment: @David Jon's post is _the_ answer.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: I don't know, Oded seems to have a competing post now.  I say they fight it out.

Comment: @David Ya, some good points - navigation is a bit messed up though, and being nonlinear makes it less digestable, IMO.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: All coding blogs must be closed as exact duplicates of Jon Skeet's.

Comment: @Oded That is awesome stuff!

Comment: @jadarnel27 - Thanks for the kind words

Comment: Our [faq] tag has many good questions regarding this topic.  If you check out [this list of faq questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), at the bottom I also have been adding relevant external links with pretty good information about asking technical questions.  Good stuff.